# Comparing Images for common features/patterns

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

[image][image]I have a collection of more than 100 images. Although I am able to see the common patterns between all of them I was asked to write some kind of the script/program to check for similarities or degree of similarity between them.

All of the images are 255x255 in size. There are only two colors black and white. In the most cases images are composed of three primitive shapes:

- Squares/rectangles
- Vertical/horizontal/diagonal lines
- Blob/cloud like shapes stretched diagonally on the image

This shapes in the most cases are in the same place on the images but in different sizes and shapes. For example squares appears in the corners of the image but in different sizes.

My question is : Is there any kind of the software that can give me a numerical value that would represent the degree of similarity between images?

Comment: [SIFT or SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) might be a start, or maybe [something like this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html).

Comment: can you some of your images ?

Comment: @Roger Will that work for this images? It is basically a visual representation of some data. This shapes are not so continues as you can see

Comment: @articuno here are two images

Comment: Why are they having so much noise? I think you should start with a median filter (medianBlur), then see if it is making better or worse the images. Then I am not really sure what does the degree of similarity means, would a subtraction, then counting the pixels, help you?

Comment: I do not see the blob shape in your image, but you can also try to detect lines in your image (hough lines)

Comment: @SzymonKrawczyk No, it won't work unless you have much cleaner inputs. Maybe your first question should be how to pre-process these images before feature detection. If you know what kind of shapes/sizes to expect, you might be able to use a custom kernel for finding matches via convolution.

Comment: Noise is due to the out liners in the data. These two images are visualizations of the two different bmp images that has been encrypted with  some cbc xor encryption using that little program -> [link](http://code.google.com/p/xorencryption/) 
I use couple of different algorithms to generate that images. The goal is to create the tool that would be able to distinguish different obfuscation techniques.
 My goal is to map different patterns to different encoding/encryption/obfuscation techniques

Comment: Rather than converting your data to images and then trying to analyse features, it might be less work (and more reliable) to just train an SVM on your original data.

Comment: @Roger I was thinking about using the n-gram with naive Bayesian classifier to do its work on raw data(before processing).
Isn't SVM used mainly in the image processing?

Comment: SVM is just another machine learning algorithm. At the end of the day they are all equal (Google "no free lunch theorem"). If you're looking for measures of similarity, SVM would be *my* first choice.

Comment: I will definitely take look on that. I hope I will not run of time cause all of that is a pretty complex stuff...
Thank all of you for recommendations and tips

Comment: How about giving us 3 or 4 of the proper 255x255 size images instead of screengrabs with borders and two images in?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute these operations and match them:

1. Median filter / Erode / Dilate
2. Compute gradients of images (Scharr, Sobel) to extract strong patterns
3. Compute Hough lines transform or contours extraction on the result of 2

4a. Perform Mahalanobis distance on HU moments from the result of 3

4b. (Alternative) compute histograms and match them on results of 3

One of the best libraries so far is OpenCV (http://www.opencv.org), which is well documented (docs.opencv.org)

Comment: The images the OP posted are much too noisy to use any of these techniques without some pre-processing.

Comment: the gradients are part of preprocessing.

Comment: Scharr/Sobel is unlikely to be effective on those images, I think it would need at least median filtering beforehand - possibly worth trying some of these on the OP's images and post the results in your answer. That would be useful.

Comment: @RogerRowland Median filter improves it (I've updated my reply). Also erode/dilate can remove part of the noise

Comment: Ok what programming library/suite you recommend?
Should I use openCV?

Comment: Using OpenCV is good with python, for creating scripts, but you can use it with C++ or you can use Matlab for validating the approach, but I suggest you to do it with OpenCV for being closed to the task